# Is it possible to create a default stage for all the build plans on Atlassian Bamboo?

Tags: continuous-integration, build-process, bamboo, continuous-delivery

Is it possible for the Atlassian Bamboo's administrator to create a default stage and have it automatically added to all the build plans( both existing and new build plans ) ? This stage should be read only to the users, meaning they should not be able to modify this stage.

This feature will let the administrator do certain house keeping things on the bamboo agents each time a new build job starts running on the agent.

I tried to search for it in the Atlassian's documentation but could not find anything as such.

Answer (score 0):

We are talking about two things: a) stage Level Permission , b) adding one default stage to all plans. 
Adding one default stage to all plans: You can create one template plan with default stage and permission. Every time a new plan creation request comes, you can just clone this template plan and add additional steps/repos etc.  But for already existing plans, you will have to modify them individually. 
 Whereas I know, Bamboo provides plan level permission. You can give View/Build permission to users and Edit/Clone type of permissions to Bamboo administrators. 
In your scenario, is user allowed to edit other stages except default stage?Why do you want user to be able to edit Build Plans?